# Read-only monitoring

Tags: bash, zabbix

So im trying to make a read only filesystem monitoring for all my centos servers. At first it seemed easy but then i ran into a conflict. Basicly i made a script to check and zabbix to monitor the outcome but each server has 1 Read only mount that stops me from getting the correct data.

```
#!/bin/bash

if cat /proc/mounts | grep RO  | grep "\srw" > /dev/null
    then
            echo 1
    else
            echo 0

fi
```

So this script will check for read only mounts perfectly but the outcome for "cat /proc/mounts" will allways result in "tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0" meaning the monitoring will allways tell me i have an readonly mount. Does anyone know how to make script skip this or has even a better way to monitor readonly ?

Comment: if `findmts` is available maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering out `tmpfs` using: `| grep -v tmpfs`

Answer (score 0):

The [`cat` is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and you probably want to avoid stringing several `grep`s in a pipeline.

```
if awk '/RO/ && !/tmpfs/ && /[ \t]rw/ { print 1; true=1; exit 0}
    END { if(!true) { print 0; exit 1 }}' /proc/mounts
```

The `\s` escape is a Perl extension which is not generally portable; in Awk and portable `grep` you can use an explicit character class, or the POSIX symbolic class `[[:space:]]`.